# When should i assign independent states to child functions(using hooks) in react?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, react-hooks, state, react-state

I am making a small project in react which has three child components

1. a form to input data and later that data is posted to server
2. Another form to input a key and later fetch its corresponding value from server
3. Live Display of current data present on server

As of now i have declared all the states required in this project in a function which is a parent of all the functions mentioned above.

I believe i can also declare relevant states separately in child functions independently instead of declaring them in their common parent and the project would work fine .

So ,my question is

what should be the right approach to declare states in above example project ? OR like what is the correct approach in designing architecture for states in general ?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. make sure to add your current progress (code you are working with), actual output and desired output to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally state variable is create in most parent component that needs to read/change the state.

- When a child need to read the state, parent passed down it to child as
  a prop.
- When a child need to write into state, parent pass a callback
  function as a prop to child to modify the state.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'correct archi'. Just respect the core concept of separation of concerns and you will be forced to build a clean architecture.

For state management, it depend on your needs. I usually love to implement contextApi to handle my stuff but it's just a choice, and it's because i have to share data between multiples components. If you are sure your application won't get fat then handling local state isn't a bad solution, it's easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

In general and the proper way to declare the states is to define them inside the functional(parent) component. Since you are using hook, you can use **React.useState()** to define your states.

Eg.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState);
```

And to change the value of states later, you can simply call the child functions and use the hook function inside to change the value.

```
setState(newState);
```